# Use macro within implementation of trait with async functions

Tags: rust, async-await, traits

Here's a minimal example for using an `async` function in a trait:

```
use async_trait::async_trait;

macro_rules! default_f {
    () => {
        async fn f() -> i32 { 0 }
    };
}

#[async_trait]
trait Tr {
    async fn f() -> i32;
}

struct S;

#[async_trait]
impl Tr for S {
    default_f!();  // error: `async` trait functions are not currently supported
    //async fn f() -> i32 { 42 }  // this compiles
}
```

Async functions in traits are not supported, yet (rustc 1.53), but the [async_trait](https://docs.rs/async-trait) crate provides a workaround.

The slightly unusual thing, here, is the use of a macro to define a default implementation for the function `f`.

I don't quite see why I can't use a macro, here. My guess is that the `async_trait` macro and the the `default_f` macro don't play well together.

With boilerplate the correct macro looks like this

```
macro_rules! default_f {
    () => {
        fn f<'a>() -> Pin<Box<dyn core::future::Future<Output = i32> + Send + 'a>>
        where Self: Sync + 'a, 
        { 
            async fn f() -> i32 { 42 }
            Box::pin(f())
        }
    };
}
```

Is there a way to make this work without having to do the boilerplate?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e31484ccf9034cf01ea1c58e64605cce)

Comment: I noticed a similar issue combining `async_trait` with `fehler::throws` in the same trait. I did a workaround, something like this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a6f3c5b48b5a653d6f300266bd67c2fe). Not 100% satisfactory, but good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the async_trait inside of the macro_rule, that way the async_trait is expanded after your macro rules.

```rs
macro_rules! define_f {
    (
        $(#[$meta:meta])*
        pub trait $trait:ident {
            [$(($name:ident, $ty:ty)),*]
        }
    ) => {
        $(#[$meta])*
        pub trait $trait {
            $(
                async fn $name() -> $ty;
            )*
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! impl_f {
    (
        $(#[$meta:meta])*
        impl $trait:ident for $impl_ty:path {
            [$(($name:ident, $ty:ty, $expr:expr)),*]
        }
    ) => {
        $(#[$meta])*
        impl $trait for $impl_ty {
            $(
                async fn $name() -> $ty {
                    $expr
                }
            )*
        }
    };
}
```

and then usage looks like this,

```rs
define_f! {
    #[async_trait::async_trait]
    pub trait Tr {
        [
            (f, i32)
        ]
    }
}

struct S;

impl_f! {
    #[async_trait::async_trait]
    impl Tr for S {
        [
            (f, i32, 3)
        ]
    }
}
```

Playground link,

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f5d63a228108634fe883e19948eea6ed